# Link thumbnails in slider to the main display image and pop up correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html, joomla2.5

There are 3 things I want to achieve here, namely

1. Lightbox
2. Thumbnails slider
3. Cloud zoom

I am able to get the 3)Cloud zoom & 2)Thumbnail slider [working](http://webclicks.biz/test/365/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=143&virtuemart_category_id=7), but I am unsure how to link the thumbnails in the slider to the main display image and pop up with the right selection.

Can anybody shed a light? Thanks in advance!

#### I declared this at the top:

```
<pre>$document->addScriptDeclaration("     
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#flexible-zoom-additionalImagesWrap').jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: '.next',
                btnPrev: '.prev',
                visible: 2,
                scroll: 1,
                circular: false             
                 });     
  });

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('.flexibleGallery').colorbox({rel:'flexibleGallery'});
   });   

jQuery.fn.flexibleZoom.defaults = {
        position: 'right',
        zoomWidth: '360',
        zoomHeight: '470',
        lensOpacity: 0.5, 
        smoothMove: 7,
        adjustX: 10,
        adjustY: 0,
        showTitle: true,        
    }; 
");
</pre>
```

#### and here are the html/php codes

```
<?php // Product Main Image
if (!empty($this->product->images[0])) {
?>
<div class="main-image">
  <?php 
echo $this->product->images[0]->displayMediaFull('class="medium-image modal" id="medium-image"', true, 'class="flexible-zoom"', true, 'alt="Zoom Type 1: Standard"', true); ?>
</div>
<div class="flexible-zoom-magnify"> <a id="flexible_lightbox" class="flexibleGallery"> <span class="flexible-zoom-magnify"></span> </a> </div>
<?php } // Product Main Image END ?>

<?php
// Showing The Additional Images
if (!empty($this->product->images) and count ($this->product->images)>1) {
    ?>
<div class="additional-images"> 
  <?php          
     // Product Images slider    
     if($this->product->images[0]->virtuemart_media_id!=0 && count($this->product->images)>0)  {
        echo " < div id=\"flexible-zoom-additionalImagesWrap\" class=\"flexible-zoom-additionalImagesWrap\">";      
        echo " <div class=\"more-views-arrow prev\">
</div>";        
        echo " <div class=\"flexible-zoom-additionalImages\">";
         echo "<ul class=\"additionalImagesslider\">";
         foreach($this->product->images as $a=>$b){
            $imgsrc = JURI::root().$b->file_url;
            $imgsrc_thumb = JURI::root().$b->file_url_thumb;    
            echo "<li class=\"flexible-zoom-additionalImages-slide\">
            <a name=\"$imgsrc_thumb\"  rel=\"useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '$imgsrc_thumb\" class=\"flexible-zoom-gallery\" href=\"".$imgsrc."\">
            <img class=\"zoom-tiny-image-additional\" src=\"".$imgsrc_thumb."\"/>
            </a>
            <a class=\"flexibleGallery cboxElement\" href=\"".$imgsrc."\"></a>
            </li>";
         }       
         echo "</ul>";
         echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"more-views-arrow next\"></div>";     
         echo "</div>";  }
     ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php
} // Showing The Additional Images END ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify me, I want to open the pop up from the thumnails, is that it?

Comment: did you try this http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

I have a live implementation working of what I think you want. Have a look [here](http://www.flyhobbies.com/Stick-40-Plus).

I have a main image that can be zoomed on mouseover, up to 6 thumbnails below the main image that when clicked will show as the main image and has a link below main image to click to enlarge in a lightbox. Even has the ability for a thumbnail to be a video that plays in place of the main image.